# use sessions out of the views django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-sessions

I made a Custom template tag using [**this**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) doc like this in my Django application :

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        myCustomTags.py
    views.py
```

in the `myCustomTags.py`, I need to use some variables that there are in views.py
so I save those variables in session , and tried to get them in `myCustomTags.py`, but noting worked and it does not recognized my sessions.
I used [**this**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views) doc ,but it seems that this method wants me to use session_keys. in this method **my question** is that how to use the sessions without the key or somehow pass the keys from views.py to `myCustomTags.py` too .

here is my code in this method:

*views.py:*

```
from importlib import import_module
from django.conf import settings
SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
my_session = SessionStore()

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        # some process to validate and etc...
        my_session['test_session'] = 'this_is_my_test'
        my_session.create()
        return redirect(reverse('basic_app:index'))
```

*myCustomTags.py*

```
from django import template
from importlib import import_module
from django.conf import settings
SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

my_session = SessionStore()
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def userStatusMode():
    status = my_session['test_session']
    return status
```

*base.html*:

```
{% load dynamic_vars %}
{% userStatusMode as user_status_thing %}
 <!-- and somewher in base.html -->
{{user_status_thing}}
```

the other method was to use requst.sessions in views.py and try to get them in myCustomTags.py that didn't worked too.

by the way , how can I use session outside of the views ?
am I missing something here ?

Comment: To pass session variable to your template, you should probably use the context.

Comment: @vctrd acctually my problem is pass my session variable to another .py file not to the html

Comment: Ok, sorry, then you should probably pass the variable as argument to functions you defined in those .py files. But you'll need to call them from the views to have access to the session

Comment: @vctrd  yea but that way I must create and call a function for each variable I wish to pass to that .py file
i thought perhaps there would be some better ways to do that

Comment: You can pass a dictionary with all session variables in one function, no need to split things.

Comment: @vctrd yea , that is useful but my variables are split in several functions 
I can use session in views to get them together and call that function just one time 
but it is not dynamic too , because if I use my functions here , if I needed a new variable I must change the function in views and in my .py file 
i mean it will take me where I want but manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all kinds of wrong.

You're not supposed to instantiate SessionStore directly. The way you've done it, you haven't given any indication of *which* user's session you are trying to get or set.

Instead you are supposed to access the session for the current user via `request.session`.

```
request.session['test_session'] = 'this_is_my_test'
```

and similarly in the template, where you can directly access the session dict (no need for a template tag):

```
{{ request.session.test_session }}
```